# Validation loss/accuracy always struck at certain threshold in LSTM

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, embedding

I have a sequence prediction problem in which, given the last `m` items(6) in a sequence I need to predict next item. There are N=60k sequences for now and for each sequence `n`, I have 6 events and I want to predict next(7th in this case) event. The dataset looks like this

```
seq_inputs = [
["AA1", "BB3", "CC4","DD5","AA2", "CC8", "CC11"], #CC11 is target
["FF1", "DD3", "FF6","KK8","AA5", "CC8", "AA2"]   #AA2 will be target
..
..
]
```

After tokenizing and separating input, target data, I have reshaped data  as (for multistep one feature many to one prediction)

```
seq = [[[ 1],  [10],  [200],  [5],   [3], [90], ],

       [[ 95], [15], [4], [11], [78],[3],
        ],
       ...
       ...
      ... #60,000 of them
      ]
  
 targets = [40,3, ... , ... ]
```

I have around `60,000 sequences` and `940 unique events (vocabulary size)`, No matter what architecture I use, My validation accuracy reach 19%( validation loss 3.5) and start decreasing and I dont get result better than 20% on test data.

I have tried `dropout`,`recurrent_dropout` (upto 0.2) in LSTM layer and I have simplified the LSTM architecture to very simple one like below, but still it doesnt get past 19% on validation accuracy(overfits I guess). I have also tried to decrease embedding size. this is the simplest model I have used without luck

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, 32, input_length=seq_len)) #seq_length
model.add(LSTM(40,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(6, 1),dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))
model.add(LSTM(20))
model.add(Dense(120,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(vocabulary_size, activation='softmax'))
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Before this, I was using a large network before with 3/4 layer of lstm with 40-80 units in each, also tried embedding size upto 500, but the performance on validation and test was same, struck at 20% even if training reaches 90%.

What can be the reason of no improvement in the validation and test acuracy beyond `19-20%`?

Comment: can you share the dataset?

Comment: @NazmulHasan Unfortunately, Data is confidential

Comment: How are you encoding the strings? what types of preprocessing did you use? Sometimes preprocessing data is more important.

Comment: use I have tokenized them with keras tokenizer ( e.g one sequnce looks like this `[ 1],  [10],  [200],  [5],   [3], [90]`)

Comment: Try to separate the wrongly predicted data and take a look into it. You can use some preprocessing techniques. The model seems fine.  After preprocessing the data, reduce the learning rate to smallest and train your model until it overfits.